# Storing an object of strings using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In Mongoose you can easily create a field as an **array of strings**, like this schema:

```
{
   ofString: [String]
}
```

It's kind of what I want, except I want to store an **object** of strings.

Basically just so I can have named keys instead of numbers.

Is this possible, or will I have to use the Mixed type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `{ofString: Object}`. `Mixed` means sometimes it will be an array, sometimes an object, sometimes a string and so on (truly anything goes).